# knockout itself adds disabled="disabled" for <a>

Tags: knockout.js

My binding:

```
<!-- ko if: $root.sArea() != null -->
...
    <a href="#" class="btn addRemove" data-bind="click: $root.editQuestion">Edycja</a>
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

and the result is:

```
<a href="#" class="btn addRemove" data-bind="click: $root.editQuestion" disabled="disabled">Edycja</a>
```

On the first binding tag  has no attribute disabled, but on the second and subsequent already has.

Why knockout added disabled attribute?

I found this code in solution

```
function EnableButtons(enable) {
    if (enable)
        $(".btn, .button").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
    else
        $(".btn, .button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

is fired twice with parameter first false, secound true, and when knokcout rebindind data he somehow "remember" disabled attribute and put this to html tag. When rebinding is call there is no disabled in html

Ok, function EnableButtons is fire before ajax call, in jquery global event

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
   ...
    EnableButtons(false);
});
```

and after ajax finish work:

```
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
  ...
        EnableButtons(true);
    });
```

but in ajax request on success i call rebinding data in observable.

Conclusion:

1. Before ajax call all buttons are disabled=""disabled",
2. on ajax success is rebinding and buttons state are still disabld.
3. At the end when ajax is competed buttons state is changed to "enabled"
4. And now when ja call rebindind data but i didn't call ajax my buttons change status to disabled, why?

Looks like knockout have html DOM cached.
If I manually enabled buttons in function ajax success then everything is ok

Comment: You'll have to post code that reproduces your issue. [The code as posted currently does *not* reproduce it.](http://jsfiddle.net/wser9sgj/1/)

Comment: It would appear disabled has been added by the EnableButtons fn. Change or remove the btn classname on your anchor.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle if possible with the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Knockout is not adding the disabled attribute, plain and simple. Some other code is doing this. It looks like you have identified a potential candidate, but without more of your code nobody will be able to help you any further.